# $S$ convex $\implies f(S)$ convex

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

Trying to prove this since no optimization book in my hands proves it. The problem is that I know nothing about $f$. Here is my pathetic attempt

Since S is convex, then $tx + (1 - t)y \in S$ for $t \in (0,1)$. I also know that $f(tx + (1 - t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1 - t)f(y)$ for any convex functions.

Comment: Is $f$ a convex function?

Comment: Oh wait never mind, it only holds if $f$ is affine. I read it wrong. I thought it was true for any $f$ and was like "whaaat?"

Comment: If $f$ real valued?

Comment: Yes, the books I have all refers to Euclidean space.

Comment: I'm guessing that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. "vector valued".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes $f$ is real valued (the question suggests this with the comment regarding convex $f$).

If $S$ is convex, it is connected. If $f$ is continuous, then $f(S) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected, hence an interval, hence convex.

If $f$ is not continuous, then it is hard to say, unless $S$ is empty or consists of a single point.

For example, if $|S| \ge 2$, then let $s \in S$, and define $f = 1_{ \{s \} }$. Then $f$ takes values $\{0,1\}$, which is clearly not convex.

Comment: And if $n > 1$, $f(x,y) = (x,x^2)$ is smooth and maps the convex set $y=0$ to the non-convex parabola $y=x^2$.

Comment: Right, continuity. OKay

Comment: @mrf: The original question seemed to imply that $f$ was real valued.

Comment: Perpaps, but the question is a bit silly for real-valued functions, since there are so few convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: @mrf: There's an uncountable collection of them :-). I'm not sure being real valued or not distinguishes the question - it is trivial to construct smooth counterexamples in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n > 1$.

Comment: Still very few ;) Note the comment about "affine" though.

Comment: @mrf: That came after my answer...